# Solution to simple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to work out the arguably simple solution to:

$$
r_0\int_{t}^{t+1}{e^{-\left(\delta + s\right)\tau}d\tau}
$$

where I believe the integral should yield:

$$
r_0{e^{-\left(\delta + s\right) t}}\frac{1 - e^{- \left(\delta + s\right)}}{\delta + s}
$$

Any thoughts kindly appreciated. For full disclosure, I am not trying to cheat my way into a maths homework, but actually double checking the solution in [Bessen (2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.respol.2008.02.005) and [Gupeng and Xiangdong (2012)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chieco.2012.02.002), which happens to be different (e.g. Eq. (2) of both works).

UPDATE: Thank you @ZaidAlyafeai for the quick feedback. Allow me to elaborate a bit. Both papers aim at estimating patent value by modelling patent returns as an exponentially decaying return function accruing from patent use:

$$
r\left(t\right) = r_0 e^{-\delta t}
$$

where $r_0$ is the initial rent from the patent application, assumed to follow a lognormal distribution, and $\delta$ is depreciation rate. Now the necessary and sufficient condition for a given patent to be renewed at time $t$ is:

$$
\int_{t}^{t+1}{r\left(t\right)e^{-s\tau}d\tau} \geq c_{t}
$$

where $c_t$ is the renewal/maintenance fee and $s$ is a discount rate. Plugging the functional form of $r\left(t\right)$ into the optimal condition above and solving for the integral, the authors derive this optimal condition (Eq. (2)):

$$
r_0{e^{-\delta t}}\frac{1 - e^{- \left(\delta + s\right)}}{\delta + s} \geq c_t
$$

presented by substituting $z_t = {e^{-\delta t}}\frac{1 - e^{- \left(\delta + s\right)}}{\delta + s}$ in the form:

$$
r_0z_t \geq c_t
$$

Comment: So the difference between your solution and the equation given in the paper is that extra $s$ in the exponent ${e^{-\left(\delta + s\right) t}}$ ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai correct. As Bessen (2008) presents a couple of other harmless typos (carried over from the Working Paper draft), I may be inclined to think that the formula above suffers from the same lack of editorial oversight. However, once I found the same optimal condition stated in these exact terms in Gupeng and Xiangdong (2012), I started to doubt my basic mathematical skills.